# kafka-strams leftJoin produce NPE

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have the next values in topics

```
// photos
1, {"id": 1, user_id: 1, "url": "http://example.com"}
2, {"id": 2, user_id: 2, "url": "http://example1.com"}
3, {"id": 3, user_id: 1, "url": "http://example2.com"}

// users
1, {"id": 1, "name": "user1"}
2, {"id": 2, "name": "user2"}
```

I want to get info: `[photo_id, photo_url, user_id, user_name]`

I implement Result class for it

```
 public class Result {
  public int photo_id;
  public String photo_url;
  public int user_id;
  public String user_name;

  public static Result from(Photo photo, User user) {
    Result r = new Result();
    r.photo_id = photo.id;
    r.photo_url = r.url;
    r.user_id = user.id;
    r.user_name = user.name;
    return r;
  }
 }
```

And my stream implementation:

```
final KStream<Integer, Photo) photo_by_user = ...;
final KStream<Integer, User) users = ...;

users.leftJoin(photo_by_user, new ValueJoiner<User, Photo, Result> {
  public Result apply(User user, Photo photo) {
    return Result.from(user, photo);
  }
}, JoinWindows.of(1L))
```

But when I run this code, I get:

```
    Exception in thread "example-StreamThread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at myapps.util.Result.create(Result.java:15)
  at myapps.Example$1.apply(Example.java:56)
  at myapps.Example$1.apply(Example.java:53)
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamKStreamJoin$KStreamKStreamJoinProcessor.process(KStreamKStreamJoin.java:87)
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
```

Because `User have a value`, but `Photo` is `null`

But I do not understand why? And how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with **leftJoin** you can have null Photo values inside `ValueJoiner` `apply` method.

for each input record of `users` stream that does not satisfy the join predicate the provided ValueJoiner will be called with a null value for the `photo_by_user` stream.

inside `Result.from()` method you need to check that Photo instance is non null, and only after that get photo's fields id and url.

Also you have left join with `JoinWindows.of(1L)`, where 1 is millisecond.
pay attention that two records are only joined if their timestamps are close to each other as defined by specified `JoinWindows`. potentially in your case two records were created not exactly at the same time, so try to increase value e.g. 10000L to test your joining logic.

Comment: Is it possible create join with all values?

Comment: if you need inner join, use `.join()` instead of `.leftJoin()`. if you want to join despite when records were created (ignoring timestamp), I guess you need KTable join